# How do I replicate the functionality of selecting contacts in messaging app?

Tags: android, messaging, android-widget, contacts, autocompletetextview

Android's messaging app, located in projects/platform/packages/apps/Mms.git has a class called RecipientsEditor. I would like to be able to create MultiAutoCompleteTextView that will filter contacts the same way, to make contact selection easy in my app. using the mms app is cumbersome since it uses internal apis and has everything split across classes.

Has anyone made an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea for public applications but you can use code and resources from other applications if you have the right class loader. I [wrote about it](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/apk-piracy), using `createPackageContext` and some reflection.